# Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial - MacBook Pro 2018 Dualbooting problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, kernel, acpi

I am trying to do dual boot on my MacBook Pro 2018 model version Catalina 10.15.2 with Ubuntu 16.04 (because I need ROS kinetic and only 16.04 supports it).

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my USB Flash Drive(8Gb) by flashing it with the “Etcher” program. For this, I downloaded the iso file from the original Ubuntu site. And I created an empty 50Gb space in my SSD. I did this from Disc Utility (From “Kapsayıcı disk1 to LINUX(50GB) ). In the picture, I show you the situation on my SSD Drive. And also you can see the flash drive on that list which is named “Innostor.”

[Disc Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDOQI.png)

The problem is when I restarted my Mac and hold down the option key, after choosing the EFI Boot and then “Install Ubuntu” choice, I get a black screen and some codes related to ACPI Errors and finally get Kernel panic Exit code. Can you help me why I get these errors even though I did the basic things? I changed the security on my Macbook and gave access to install different types of software.

You can see the picture of the error below.

[EFI BOOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmzyW.jpg)
[Install Ubuntu Choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7CDZ.jpg)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJWvl.jpg)

Comment: Try changing filetype of the partition.

Comment: You mean the type like MS-DOS(FAT32)? It is already like that both the USB drive and the partititon I made.